# Is it possible to make my Windows Python installation aware of extra libraries it can use when running inside a Cygwin terminal?

Tags: python, cygwin, anaconda

I would like to use the following Python package, which requires `ncurses`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings

I have the Windows version of Anaconda Python installed, and designated as my Python distribution.
I have also have a Cygwin installation. When I run `python -i` within the provided Cygwin terminal, Anaconda Python starts up -- great!

If I then try `import blessings`, I'll get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\blessings\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import curses
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: No module named _curses
```

Alright, so what's happening is that Anaconda Python is understandably not picking up Cygwin's curses.

Now, does it even make sense to try and somehow make Anaconda aware of `ncurses`, only within the context of usage in a Cygwin terminal? I suspect it isn't, and that I am missing something conceptually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use Cygwin Python's curses module with CPython unfortunately. Modules for the two Pythons are incompatible for the following reasons (and more):

Windows Python directly calls the Win32 API (via either the Visual Studio 2008, 2010 or 2015 C-Runtimes) while Cygwin Python links to the Cygwin POSIX API which is layered on top of the Visual Studio 6.0 C-Runtime. Mixing different C-Runtimes in a single process is a very bad idea: http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/, never mind further abstracted through a POSIX API.

Regardless of the C-Runtime differences, Cygwin implements the LP64 model while Windows implements the LLP64 model which would make the 64-bit size of `long` different between each, so some structures could be differently sized. They would likely be anyway due to #ifdefs in the code.

Is there any reason you can't use [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama/0.2.4)?
The documentation for blessings suggests that should work.

Comment: Well, I still need to install something like curses, for `blessings` to work, right? Does `colorama` even matter if you can't import `blessings` because there's no `curses`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems you are right. I think porting ncurses to build with Visual Studio would be the best course of action here. It seems there used to be something called UniCurses but it used PDCurses which doesn't use the modern Windows Console API, and so I wouldn't bother with. Porting ncurses to Visual Studio is probably not for the faint of heart though.